# Why is my tooltip in a wrong position?

Tags: css, d3.js, modal-dialog, tooltip

I have made a tooltip using this:

```
var tooltip = d3.select("#d3tooltip")
    .append("div")
    .style("position", "absolute")
    .style("z-index", "10")
    .style("visibility", "hidden")
    .text("a simple tooltip");
```

And my html:

```
<div id="d3">
<div id="d3tooltip"></div>
<div id="d3present"></div>
</div>
```

The svg is appended to 'div#d3present'.When a node is mouseovered,the tootip shows beside the node.It works fine in one html.

However,When I render this into a dialog,the tooltip is not close to the node any more,in fact, it runs down to the bottom of the dialog.

I have been working on it all day,any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the css styles of <div id="d3"> tag?

When browser renders an "position: absolute" element, it will find the element's first parent whose position is not static, which means relative/absolute or fixed, until body, and then render the element with position to that element.

By default every element's position attribute is static.

So if your #d3 tag doesn't have a relative or absolute position, and your modal dialog has an absolute or fixed position, then browser will render your tooltip relative to that one.

Could you check your tooltips parent position settings?

Comment: I changed the css style if "#d3" to absolute,But nothing have changed,I still got that problem.

Comment: I think you are right,But it seems that my tooltip is always at the right bottom of the page,should I add more information to <div id="d3"> tag in order to "fix" the tooltip's position?

Comment: I will suggest set the #d3 element to relative without any top/left/right/bottom settings. So that browser will show it like static element. Then except setting the position:absolute to your tooltip, try some "top:10%; left:40%" css styles. These are the real position parameters.

Comment: But if I set 10% and 40%,My tooltip is always in one place.How do I change its position just near my node?